# Deeplearning4j Disable Logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, deeplearning4j

I have a deeplearning for java project which is producing huge amounts of logger output on STDO. I want to disable that but I cant seem to figure out how to do it.

I have a `log4j.properties` file in my src/main/resources folder which looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Console
log4j.logger.play=WARN
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n

log4j.appender.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.appender.org.nd4j=WARN
log4j.appender.org.canova=WARN
log4j.appender.org.datavec=WARN
log4j.appender.org.deeplearning4j=WARN
log4j.appender.opennlp.uima=OFF
log4j.appender.org.apache.uima=OFF
log4j.appender.org.cleartk=OFF

log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.nd4j=WARN
log4j.logger.org.canova=WARN
log4j.logger.org.datavec=WARN
log4j.logger.org.deeplearning4j=WARN
log4j.logger.opennlp.uima.util=OFF
log4j.logger.org.apache.uima=OFF
log4j.logger.org.cleartk=OFF
log4j.logger.org.deeplearning4j.optimize.solvers.BaseOptimizer=OFF
slf4j.logger.org.deeplearning4j.optimize.solvers.BaseOptimizer=OFF
```

The specific output that is far too much is:

`21:26:34.860 [main] DEBUG o.d.optimize.solvers.BaseOptimizer - Hit termination condition on iteration 0: score=1.2894165074915344E19, oldScore=1.2894191699433697E19, condition=org.deeplearning4j.optimize.terminations.EpsTermination@55f111f3`

which happens multiple times a second while training.

Comment: Have you tried adding `log4j.appender.org.deeplearning4j=WARN` to your `log4j.properties`?

Comment: @DanW thats already in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the log entry that you have provided look very much as the SLF4J output with [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) format (not LOG4J output).

Also dependencies of [deeplearning4j-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.9.1) advice SLF4J is used for logging.

Hence your `log4j.properties` have no effect on deeplearning4j logging. Try to add `logback.xml` configuration to the resources as well and switch to WARN or ERROR level for root logger, see https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some properties in the framework DL4J (1.0.0-beta7) that activate/deactivate the logs. I found some of them:

```
import org.nd4j.common.config.ND4JSystemProperties;

System.setProperty(ND4JSystemProperties.LOG_INITIALIZATION, "false");
System.setProperty(ND4JSystemProperties.ND4J_IGNORE_AVX, "true");
System.setProperty(ND4JSystemProperties.VERSION_CHECK_PROPERTY, "false");
```

Notice that this is an unconventional solution. On the other hand, there are some messages impossible to avoid:

```
MultiLayerNetwork.init()
```

In this method you can find a OneTimeLogger without validations:

```
    OneTimeLogger.info(log, "Starting MultiLayerNetwork with WorkspaceModes set to [training: {}; inference: {}], cacheMode set to [{}]",
            layerWiseConfigurations.getTrainingWorkspaceMode(),
            layerWiseConfigurations.getInferenceWorkspaceMode(),
            layerWiseConfigurations.getCacheMode());
```

If you find a better way to disable log messages inside DL4J please share it. There are some other ways outside the DL4J library.